# How can I get object's property name by its value [JS]

Tags: javascript, oop

```
questions={
     1:{
          quest: "blah blah blah",
          answers: ["1812", "1837", "1864", "1899"],
          correct: "1837"
     },
     2:{
         quest: "fasfa asf",
         answers : ["2","3","4","5"],
         correct : "3"
     }
 }
```

For example, I know value of `1`. I need to get that object's name with its value.
     
`var x = {quest: "blah blah blah",
answers: ["1812", "1837", "1864", "1899"],
correct: "1837"}`

`returnNameOf(x)` expected output `1`;

Comment: `questions[1]` ?

Comment: nope :)))))))))

Comment: Whoops, sorry, skipped the last line ...

Comment: You want to get output as `1` when input is `{quest: "blah blah blah",
answers: ["1812", "1837", "1864", "1899"],
correct: "1837"}`?

Comment: Does `x` *point to* the question or is it another object with the same values?

Comment: Maheer Ali, yes exactly

Comment: Johnas Wilms, `x` is just variable for question

Comment: What do you get when you do `x === questions[1]` ? `true` or `false` ?

Comment: Could you just use `quest` as the key instead of the whole object?

Comment: IllusiveBrian, yeah why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` on `Object.keys()` and compare objects using `JSON.stringify()`

```js
let questions={
     1:{
          quest: "blah blah blah",
          answers: ["1812", "1837", "1864", "1899"],
          correct: "1837"
     },
     2:{
         quest: "fasfa asf",
         answers : ["2","3","4","5"],
         correct : "3"
     }
 }
 
 let val = {
         quest: "fasfa asf",
         answers : ["2","3","4","5"],
         correct : "3"
     }
function getKey(obj,value){
  if(typeof value === "object"){
    value = JSON.stringify(value);
    return Object.keys(obj).find(key => JSON.stringify(obj[key]) === value);
  }
  else return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);
}

console.log(getKey(questions,val));
```

Comment: Do caching `Object.keys(obj)` helps in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to string and use in comparison. So in this example we need to find the key whose value matches with `toMatch`. Therefore in the function `toMatch` is converted to string since object matching or object equality test will return false as they compare memory location

```js
let toMatch = {
  quest: "blah blah blah",
  answers: ["1812", "1837", "1864", "1899"],
  correct: "1837",
};

let questions = {
  1: {
    quest: "blah blah blah",
    answers: ["1812", "1837", "1864", "1899"],
    correct: "1837"
  },
  2: {
    quest: "fasfa asf",
    answers: ["2", "3", "4", "5"],
    correct: "3"
  }
}


function findKey(objString) {
  let val = JSON.stringify(toMatch)
  for (let keys in questions) {
    if (JSON.stringify(questions[keys]) === val) {
      return keys;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findKey(toMatch))
```

Comment: It works, but my json file contains much more objects and comparison will be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could search in the Objects entries:

```
const key = 0, value = 1;

const result = Object.entries(questions).find(it => it[value] === x)[key];
```